# Can you talk with a non-Mahram if you are gay (but of course won't do any homosexual acts)?

Tags: practical-islam, homosexuality, non-mahram

I am a 14 year old Muslim, and have had same-sex attraction since I was about 9. I know that homosexual acts are not allowed in Islam, and *Insha Allah*, I'll never do these acts. But what I want to know is that can I talk to non-Mahrams? I feel literally **no** sexual attraction towards females. So can I?

Answer (score 2):

As-salaam walikum Brother,

The answer is no. This is because:

1. She might be attracted to you. Which is likely as most women are attracted to men.
2. This increases the chance of zina, which is less likely in your case but more likely if you openly talk to non-Mahrams?

Comment: W/salaam. Thank you very much